# Is possible to efficiently skip a line of an unknown size in Java?

Tags: java, file

While reading very huge files (GB scale) in Java, I know exactly which lines I need to process. But, I do not know the size of each line and they could be different.

**My question is the following:**

Do you have an efficient approach to skip useless lines ? My (naive) approach consists of reading the line and not process it, but It sounds like a waste of time and memory space.

The code I'm looking for can look like this :

```
SortedMap goodLineNumbers = ......

Int  currentLineNumber = 1;

try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tracefile))) {

    do{
         if(goodLineNumbers.containsKey(currentLineNumber)) {
               line = br.readLine();    
               // process line
         } else  {
              line = EfficientSkip(br); // don't know the size of the line
         }
         currentLineNumber++;
    }
    while(line != null);
} catch (IOException e) {           
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why do you store useless lines in a variable ?

Comment: Have you measured the impact of redundant reads on your performance? How do you know that introducing complications to your solution would pay off? Especially since you're not about to save on any I/O volume, just some memory allocation.

Comment: I can not actually measure this impact since I can not compare it to the case where I really skip those lines. Or do you mean measuring io and memory activities of my approach ? If so, do you mind giving me ways (links to resources) to do that because I don't know how to measure them.

Comment: @Raphaël I would like to avoid doing that ! and that is the purpose of my question. Any idea about how to avoid storing those useless lines are welcome ;-)

Comment: I am not sure it is possible if you have different line length and you dont save them in somewhere. "line" means actually "\n" char. so eventually, you have to count this chars. but, if you can create a well format for your file, like keeping line index at start of file, you might go to a specific position easily with RandomAccessFile

Comment: If you want to consume many lines, you can read the newline N times and ignore everything else.  Text files are not designed for random access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ownership over file's format, you can add a length of each line before writing it, a kind of a header. This will let you jump from line to line, whiteout reading it up to the end. For this task you might use [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) instead of BufferedReader.

readLong() - read line's length

readLine() - if this is required line

skipBytes(int n) - otherwise

Comment: (1) that will need to pay the cost of updating the **huge** file. (2) If the length of the line is in the same file, then we need at least to read it, so finally  we still read the useless line.

Comment: (1) Everything depend on your case. If you create file once and read it multiple times, this is reasonable solution. (2) You can read file by bytes, not only by lines.

Comment: So the idea is to add (in advance) the lenght of each line before the data it contains. The length need to be represented in a fixed number of bytes so that I can read it easilly. Sound nice I will give a try ! thank

Comment: Unless the line is longer than a few thousand characters, it is faster to just read it completely, then do this

Comment: Why? Skipping a big lines is even more efficient then a small one.

Comment: If you are willing to experiment, and it is possible to change the file format, I think, a more promising approach would be prepending each line with the line number (not length), and binary searching the file. That can give you some performance gain, depending on how sparse your set of "good" lines is.

Comment: @Mikhail, yes, that's what I said. If the lines are extremely long, this *might* be somewhat efficient (but, probably, still not because of buffering). With lines shorter than FS page size (usually either 4 or 8K), it will most probably be slower, then just scanning for line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want BufferedReader create Strings for lines you dont need, read input by char, count lines by EOL and use BufferedReader.readLilne() when you are at the beginning of the line you need. I am not sure if it will improve overall performance though.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try using a LineNumberReader instead. You can get / set the current line to read.
That way, you could just access and read those lines you want. Period.</strike>

Thanks to Dima for pointing out that LineNumberReader cannot access by line number either.

Thinking more on the problem, it is theoretically impossible to determine at what point in the file a certain line begins, unless one either:
A) has prior knowledge of the (combined) length of previous lines, or
B) reads the whole file up to that given point (with or without processing the contents).

Comment: From javadoc: "Note however, that setLineNumber(int) does not actually change the current position in the stream; it only changes the value that will be returned by getLineNumber()."

Comment: Thank you, Dima! It appears that I was overly optimistic about the usefulness of LineNumberReader.
Please disregard my answer, Fopa. My apologies.

Comment: If your answer is not helpful you should delete it

Comment: I considered this, StormeHawke. However, it might prove useful to people who make the same assumption I did. Instead, I will edit the answer accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic. To know how many lines you have read, you have to read them one by one and count. You don't have to store useless lines (`while (count++ < nextGoodNumber && reader.readLine() != null);` will do), but you do have to read them one by one.

Comment: With this approach, I wonder what will happen when I will meet the line that I need to process. This line will not be lost because of the previous `reader.readLine()` which was not stored ?

Comment: Why would it be lost? You end the `while` loop after the previous line. Now you can read the one you were looking for. Look, suppose, you are looking for line #10. So read the first nine with `count = 0; while(++count++ < 10) reader.readLine();`. Now `count == 10`, and you can read the tenth line with `line=reader.readLine();` (I omitted the null checks for brevity, keep in mind, that they are still needed).

Comment: Now I see your point, but I'm interested about many lines not just one. Can you improve your proposal by taking into account this new fact ?

Comment: Oh, come on. Put another loop around it.
`curLine = 0; for(int lineNum: goodLines) { while(++curLine < lineNum && reader.readLine() != null); String goodLine = reader.readLine(); processGoodLine(goodLine, lineNum); }`

Comment: No need. I am confident, you'll figure it out as it is ;)